# Inputting a variable in the middle of a cout using placeholders

Tags: c++, string

I want to `cout` a string with variables mixed in, using something like C# code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);
```

except with multiple placeholders.
Is there a way to do this instead of `cout << "Hello, " << name;`?

`cout << "Hello {0}", name;` is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You might be looking for [Boost.format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) or similar.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use multiple variables intermixed with text string literals, with `std::cout`, already?

Answer (score 1):

printf will do what you're looking for.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

printf("Hello %s\n", name);
```

https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet

Comment: [More complete `printf` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). Note that `printf` uses a variable argument list and will accept pretty much any argument you give it, often without any warning whatsoever if you get the matching format specifier wrong. The resulting runtime errors range from hilarious to hair-pulling.